# Forcibly releasing an already closed connection

Tags: eclipselink, connection-pooling, weblogic12c

I am using EclipseLink with JTA. when I run the application using WebLogic server *version(12.2.1.3.0)* faced the following issue

[EL Warning]: 2020-06-03 16:17:13.679--ClientSession(1584629836)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: The connection has been administratively diabled. Try again later. The action was taken by a console or administrative command. java.lang.Exception: It was disabled at Wed Jun 03 16:17:13 IST 2020
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnv.disable(ConnectionEnv.java:454)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JDBCWrapperImpl.removeConnFromPoolIfFatalError(JDBCWrapperImpl.java:159)

<**Forcibly releasing an already closed connection "[weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTAConnection_weblogic_jdbc_wrapper_XAConnection_oracle_jdbc_driver_LogicalConnection-platform-2420, ]" back into the data source connection pool "platform**".>

PS - Not facing this issue with WebLogic version(12.2.1.2.0)

Comment: Can you check your datasource configuration in both domains 12.2.12 et 12.2.1.3 ?

Comment: Both are having the same configurations

Answer (score 0):

As per a somewhat dated oracle [article](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=118548323448521&parent=EXTERNAL_SEARCH&sourceId=PROBLEM&id=1211143.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=4q4wa65b4_45), there are a number of causes, such as the database going down (temporarily or longer), or bugs in WLS itself. The bugs mentioned have been fixed, but that doesn't mean something new wasn't introduced or just some setting you had in 12.2.1.2.0 doesn't work or apply the same in 12.2.1.3.0.

Solutions vary, but check that the datasource is disabled and manually enable it through the console, and change the datasource settings so that isn't disabled unnecessarily in the future:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13737/ds_tuning.htm#JDBCA180